# sObject type 'OrderItem' is not supported in Flow Get Records on OrderItem

Tags: permissions, crud

Whilst migrating profile-based permissions to `minimum access - salesforce` + permissions + permission set groups, the running user started a screen Flow and got this error:

```
sObject type 'OrderItem' is not supported
```

- The Flow fetches an Order (successfully),
- The Get Records within the Flow does the equivalent of

  ```
  SELECT Quantity, UnitPrice 
    FROM OrderItem
    WHERE OrderId = theFetchedOrderId
  ```
- and fails with `sObject type 'OrderItem' is not supported`

The running user has R on the `Order` and consequently R on the `OrderItem` detail object.

So why does Flow think that `OrderItem` is not supported (indicating an sobject visibility issue in permissions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable true visibility to Object `OrderItem`, the running user must have

- `R` on `Pricebook` and `R` on `Product2`
- This is because `OrderItem.PricebookEntryId` is a required field and it is a junction record between  `Pricebook2` and `Product2`

[image]

I imagine the same would be true for

- `OpportunityLineItem`
- `QuoteLineItem`
- `ContractLineItem`

There are other objects that use `PricebookEntryId` (e.g. `WorkOrderLineItem` ([Obj Ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_workorderlineitem.htm?q=pricebookentryId)) but per doc, field is not required and as we don't use this object, I did not test)

*Such are the joys of moving to principle of least privilege with layered permission sets. Stuff gets inadvertently omitted in the friction of the endeavor*